# How do you resample upscale an image using wasm-vips?

Tags: webassembly, vips

[wasm-vips](https://github.com/kleisauke/wasm-vips) is a browser/node wrapper for libvips

**Goals:**

Using wasm-vips

1. Upscale image using interpolator such as lanzcos3 or nohalo
2. In the upscale method pass in a buffer instead of reading the image from a file

Example reading an image

```
 const vips = await Vips();

    let im = vips.Image.newFromFile('in.jpg');
```

But I do not know the function and properties I need to use to resample my image to 2017x2017

It looks like I need to use vips.affine as shown in the vips docs.  https://www.libvips.org/API/current/libvips-resample.html#vips-affine

The wasm-vips has the affine method  `im.affine()` but I don't know how to specify the interpolater such as lanzcos3.  I also want to pass in a uint8array instead of reading an image from a file directly.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly.  Please add it as an answer.  TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess:

```
im.resize(2017 / im.width, {kernel: 'lanczos3'})
```

And I'd look at `newFromMemory` to read from a uint8 array. Ask on the wasm-vips issue tracker:

https://github.com/kleisauke/wasm-vips

(was a comment, made into an answer on request)